# JAX-WS example not behaving in singleton manner

Tags: java, web-services

as a learner I studied that JAX-WS works in singleton manner. I tried the same with code example but it is not working in my case.

Below is my code example:

```
    package com.example.service;

    import java.util.List;

    public interface ProductService {

     public List<String> getProductCategories();

         public List<String> getProducts(String category);

     public boolean addProduct(String category, String product);

    }
```

Implementation class:

```
    package com.example.serviceImpl;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.example.service.ProductService;

    public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

List<String> bookList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> musicList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> movieList = new ArrayList<String>();

public ProductServiceImpl(){
    bookList.add("ABC");
    bookList.add("XYZ");
    bookList.add("LMNO");

    musicList.add("Random Access Memories");
    musicList.add("Night Visions");
    musicList.add("Unorthodox JukeBox");

    movieList.add("The Great and Powerful");
    movieList.add("Despicable Me");
    movieList.add("Star Trek into Darkness");

}
public List<String> getProductCategories() {
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("Books");
    categories.add("Movies");
    categories.add("Music");
    return categories;
}

public List<String> getProducts(String category) {
    switch(category.toLowerCase()){
    case "books":
        return bookList;
    case "music":
        return musicList;
    case "movies":
        return movieList;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean addProduct(String category, String product) {
    switch(category.toLowerCase()){
    case "books":
        bookList.add(product);
        break;
    case "music":
        musicList.add(product);
        break;
    case "movies":
        movieList.add(product);
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    }
```

Webservice implementation:

```
    package com.example.beans;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import com.example.service.ProductService;
    import com.example.serviceImpl.ProductServiceImpl;

    @WebService
    public class ProductCatalog {


ProductService productService = new ProductServiceImpl();

public List<String> getProductCategories(){
    return productService.getProductCategories();
}

public List<String> getProducts(String category){
    return productService.getProducts(category);
}

public boolean addProduct(String category, String product){
    return productService.addProduct(category, product);
}

    }
```

Now when I am calling getProducts after addProduct request, its returing old list only, not the updated one.

Plese let me know where I am doing wrong or missed some configuration @ glassfish server level.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any references (e.g. URL's) to the material stating a JAX-WS service is always a singleton?
AFAIK, it's just a session bean, so you would at least have to annotate it with @Singleton.
Apart from that, generally speaking I would split your web service in two: separate the catalog service from the JAX-WS web service and annotate the catalog service with @Singleton. This way your catalog service could potentially also be disclosed via a web UI, should the need arise.